# Integrations with Slack and Microsoft Teams box appear on all sites

Tags: bug, status-completed, sidebar, stack-overflow-for-teams

I've saw today this section on the main page, AFAIK I'm not using any SO Teams feature, how does it work?

This is the box on the sidebar:

> [image]

Those links are [Slack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/integrations/slack/current) and [Microsoft Teams](https://meta.stackexchange.com/teams/integrations/microsoft-teams)

This is where it sits corresponding to the rest of the site:

> [image]

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/14/announcing-our-new-partnership-with-slack/) this feature is supposed to work only with SO Teams.

Comment: Appears to be fixed now.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks for the heads up. We were diagnosing a production issue earlier and inadvertently switched on a setting that when combined with another setting meant the sidebar appeared in places it shouldn't have.

We've fixed the site setting and it is no longer displayed in places it shouldn't be!

Comment: Awesome! Also, your hair is [finally not on fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5idW.png), kudos for that as well. ;)