# User Preferences - Slack Integrations gives a 404

Tags: bug, status-review, 404-not-found, preferences, stack-overflow-for-teams

There are several earlier posts tagged [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) reflecting on this problem, like:

- ["Slack integrations" and "Microsoft Teams integrations" in Settings lead to 404](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379806/slack-integrations-and-microsoft-teams-integrations-in-settings-lead-to-404)
- [Integrations with Slack and Microsoft Teams box appear on all sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343258/integrations-with-slack-and-microsoft-teams-box-appear-on-all-sites)

but the problem seems to have re-emerged, maybe due to the Staging Ground Teams:

how to reproduce:

1. the link to your Preferences page is accessible via your
   user-profile:
   https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/$your_user_id
2. In the Preferences page you find on your left several Submenus. The
   one in question is not called TEAMS anymore, but has changed to
   INTEGRATION. Click "Slack integrations"
3. clicking that link leads you to
   https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/integrations/slack/$your_user_id which
   throws a 404

Comment: I don't see any such menu. This is Teams only issue, think MSO is the place to report bugs with Team, but since we do have a tag here not sure enough to vote to close it.

Comment: I can reproduce 404 Not Found on my profile page on ja.SO.